# cronjob for the script in subdomain not working

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, subdomain, cron

Ubuntu 14 environment 
cronjob doesnt work for a script in sub-domain directory but it did work for same script in html directory

put script for sub-domain directory by both methods (crontab -e / sudo crontab -e) with no go.

following is the sample job im trying to execute:

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/subdomain/script.php
```

any word of advise ?
its my first question on stack so please apologize me for any ignorance

Comment: I usually use RHEL. In RHEL the crond logs to the file /var/log/cron. I bet Ubuntu has the same sort of thing.  You should look in crond's log file as see what crond is doing.

Comment: they are in syslog but only info which i found suspicious is (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: nvm MTA is for mail notifications

Comment: Is the root account getting emailed the output of cronjobs? I suspect not given that message about MTA.

Comment: thanks RED got it fixed actual issue was in orignial script. its working well appreciate for your help.